# Why is R holding on to permission to modify excel files?

Tags: r, excel, windows, permissions

I am reading in some excel data into R in a loop because I have a bunch of files. This is something that I do regularly. I am having some trouble though and I'm not sure even how to make reproducible example. So i have all the files that I want in one directory and I am reading them in using this set of commands:

```
## Because I want warnings to stop the loop at a certain file so I can diagnose
options(warn=2)
xl_load_in <- c()
for (x in list.files(pattern="*\\.xls")) {
  cat(x, "\n ")
  u <- read_excel(x,col_types=c("text","text","numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric","text"))
  xl_load_in <- tbl_df(rbind(xl_load_in, u))
}
options(warn=0)
```

So this is both a tool to read in files but also, using the `warn` toggle, I can diagnose which files aren't reading in correctly.

Now the **problem**: From a fresh reboot and I can rename and save the excel files in the directory. If, however, I run the above R code, I lose the permission to save or rename the excel file where the loop broke (There are small issues with the excel files that have to rectified manually). For example if I try to rename the file upon which the loop broke I get this windows error:

> The action can't be completed because the file is open in RStudio R
>   Session.

If I reboot, I can again modify the file in question. But before the reboot I can't save or rename the file. Can anyone explain this behaviour where R or Rstudio seems to be taking over my permissions?

**Update** If I close RStudio, the permissions are returned. If I do the same sequence of commands above using RGUI for Windows, the problem in replicated indicating the issue is not an RStudio problem.

```
sessionInfo()

R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] stringr_1.1.0   readxl_0.1.1    lubridate_1.6.0 dplyr_0.5.0     purrr_0.2.2     readr_1.0.0     tidyr_0.6.0     tibble_1.2     
 [9] ggplot2_2.2.0   tidyverse_1.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.7      assertthat_0.1   R6_2.2.0         grid_3.3.2       plyr_1.8.4       DBI_0.5-1        gtable_0.2.0    
 [8] magrittr_1.5     scales_0.4.1     stringi_1.1.2    lazyeval_0.2.0   tools_3.3.2      munsell_0.4.3    colorspace_1.3-0
```

Comment: Sounds like an open connection, but `read_excel` should handle those (or they should get automatically closed after a bit, anyway). You could try `closeAllConnections()`, maybe. As an aside, a shorter way of doing what you're doing is `u <- map_df(list.files(pattern = "xls"), read_excel)`

Comment: Ok - holy doodle `map_df` is a great tip. For this application though it doesn't work as each file is just a little different (so annoying) and I need to use regex and manually parse dates within the loop. Also alas `closeAllConnections()` did not do anything in this case. Tried this on multiple computers as well still seeing the problem.

Comment: You can pass `map_df` an arbitrarily complex function in place of `read_excel` or use the `map2_df` version to iterate in parallel across a vector of dates or whatnot if you like. I'm out of ideas for the permissions issue, though, sorry.

Comment: I think the open connection hint is a good one. Also the Windows file locking mechanism does not work well with crashed processes, especially on network drives. consider using tryCatch to terminate read_excel in an ordered manner and close the connection on failure.

Comment: Thanks @snaut. I've been able to determine that it is `read_excel()` is causing the issue and specifically it is a mis-designation of `col_types()`. For example a parsing error does not hold on to the permissions.

Comment: There are certain things that go into  a process memory, which cannot be edited if opened. For example, you must have noticed before that if a file is open, it cannot be renamed. The same is the case with R. Even though the loop crashed, the files might still be in memory, leaving them in a locked state. Close all files after the loop crashes and try. If it works, edit the loop that it closes all files once the loop is not executing anymore.

Comment: Thank you @Dinesh.hmn. Can you specifically outline how to "edit the loop that it closes all files once the loop is not executing" as an answer? Then I can accept it as an answer.